# QNetworkAccessManager and POST that requires authentication

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have run into the following issue - I need to POST to a site that requires authentication. I am using `QNetworkReply* QNetworkAccessManager::post(const QNetworkRequest& request, QIODevice* data)` with a huge `Content-Length` header value (2GB).  The issue is that the 401 reply is given at once but Qt tries to upload all the data and then handle the response. So I wanted to achieve a scenario where I could initiate the POST with `Content-Length` header set to 0, provide the credentials for authentication and then together with the computed authentication response provide the actual `Content-Length` header value. However even if I set the header via a  call to `setKnownHeader` in a slot connected to the `void QNetworkAccessManager::authenticationRequired(QNetworkReply* reply, QAuthenticator* authenticator)` signal the original value (0) is still sent at the second request. Any ideas if this is even possible or do I have to handle this at lower level via `QTcpConnection` ?

Comment: How about reversing the logic -- attempting first a POST of size 0 just to check if you need authentication, fill in the `QAuthenticator`, then resubmitting with the real data?

Comment: @peppe the server is kind of badly designed and cannot properly handle another request in the same TCP connection. I already tried aborting the current cunnection in the `authenticationRequired` signal and submitting a new request on the fly, but that does not seem to get the values that I provided to the `QAuthenticator` instance (I guess because of the call to `close` ?) and I get in the same place again on the next request.

Comment: Then you can calculate the HTTP Basic Auth header yourself, and submit the request with the header manually set.

Comment: @peppe - I have not missed anything I cannot modify the headers on the original request. I tried doing that by setting the initial `Content-Length` on the `QNetworkRequest` passed to `post()` to 0 and then setting it to the real one after getting the `authenticationRequired` signal - the original value was used instead (I guess it just gets copied somewhere along the way). The issue is that I am facing digest, I could retrieve the nonce with one request and try and increase `nc` on subsequent requests but then I have to make sure the server does not invalidate that nonce. However thanks:)